# Cant finish a code, __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Hello i want to write a test program that creates an Account object with an account id of 1122, a balance of $20,000,and an annual interest rate of 4.5%. Use the withdraw method to withdraw $2,500, use the deposit method to deposit$3,000, and print the id, balance, monthly interest rate, and monthly interest but i keep getting

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given "
```

Here is how my code in file with class looks like

```py
class Account:
    def __init__(self,id=0,balance=20000,annualInterestRate=4.5):
        self.__id = id

    def getid(self):
        return self.__id

    def getbalance(self):
        return self.__balance

    def getannualInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate

    def setid(self,id):
        self.__id = id

    def setbalance(self, balance):
        self.__balance = balance

    def setannualInterestRate(self, rate):
        self.__annualInterestRate = rate

    def getMonthlyInterestRate(self):
        return self.__annualInterestRate/12

    def getMonthlyInterest(self):
        return self.__balance * self.getMonthlyInterestRate()

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount <= self.__balance:
            self.__balance -= amount
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.__balance +=amount
        return balance
```

and this is how i try to initialize it

```
  from Acc import Account

  def main():
      updatedAccount = Account(1222,20000,4.5)
      updatedAccount.withdraw(2500)
      print("User ID : ", updatedAccount.getid())
      print("Beginning Balance: ", updatedAccount.getbalance())
      print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", updatedAccount.getMonthlyInterestRate())
      print("Monthly Interest: ", updatedAccount.getMonthlyInterest())

  main()
```

Can someone please help with the last part of a code where i try to initialize it

Comment: is this the right code ? how are you using self.__balance in  withdraw without initializing ?

Comment: This code will not produce the stated error. You appear to be running an older version that didn't include `balance` or `annualInterestRate` in the definition of `__init__`.

Comment: With them *in* the definition, you need to initialize `self.__balance` and `self.__annualInterestRate` with their values. `balance` and `annualInterestRate` are local variables, and not available from, e.g., the `deposit` method.

Comment: While you are at it, drop the unnecessary getter/setter methods that do nothing but provide direct access to the underlying variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, why don't you initialize the balance and interest in the **init**() body?
Then use the setbalance or setters to set the values when the user wants to change the initial value?

Answer to your question: You provided the values to the constructor as positional arguments. Whenever you use the keyword(kwargs) argument construct, remember to explicitly set them in the function call.

Example:

```
def do_some(i=34, j=23):
```

Function call:

```
do_some(i=23,i=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your definition of `Account` *should* look:

```
class Account:
    # No need for a default id; it should be required
    # 0 is a better default for balance; banks don't give you $20,000 unless you specify otherwise :)
    def __init__(self, id, initial_balance=0, rate=4.5):
        self.id = id
        self.balance = initial_balance
        self.annual_interest_rate = rate

    # Ditch the unnecessary getters and setters

    # Example of a "computed attribute value", rather than an explicit method
    @property
    def monthly_interest_rate(self):
        return self.annual_interest_rate / 12

    def get_monthly_interest(self):
        return self.balance * self.monthly_interest_rate

    # Don't return True/False.  Do the debit, or raise an exception
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance < amount:
            raise ValueError(f"Overdraft, balance less than {amount}")

        self.balance -= amount

    # Don't return the balance; mutating methods should return None.
    # The caller can always check self.balance after the deposit
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance +=amount
```

Example usage:

```
from Acc import Account

def main():
    updatedAccount = Account(1222,20000,4.5)
    updatedAccount.withdraw(2500)
    print("User ID : ", updatedAccount.id)
    print("Beginning Balance: ", updatedAccount.balance)
    print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", updatedAccount.monthly_interest_rate)
    print("Monthly Interest: ", updatedAccount.get_monthly_interest())

main()
```